# Remover texto apos caracter JS

Tags: javascript

Preciso remover tudo o que estiver a frente do * (asterisco)
Javascript
exemplo:

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
  <label>Carro</label>
      <input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control" value="palio*Azul">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
  <label>Resultado</label>
      <input type="text" id="resultado" class="form-control" >
    </div>
  </div>
 <input type="button" id="botaoapagar" onclick="apagar();" value="Apagar">
 
</form>

<script>

function apagar(){


var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;

// Exemplo retornando só o modelo
var resultado = "palio"

 document.getElementById("resultado").value = resultado;



}</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta utilizar o método `split()` para cortar a string na primeira ocorrência do asterisco, conforme demonstrado abaixo:

```
var resultado = nome.split("*", 1);
```

No código acima, o primeiro parâmetro do método `split()` é o caracter buscado (no caso o asterisco) e o segundo é a ocorrência (no caso a primeira ocorrência).

Segue demonstração do uso do método em questão no seu código:

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
  <label>Carro</label>
      <input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control" value="palio*Azul">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
  <label>Resultado</label>
      <input type="text" id="resultado" class="form-control" >
    </div>
  </div>
 <input type="button" id="botaoapagar" onclick="apagar();" value="Apagar">
 
</form>

<script>

function apagar(){


var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
//Função split para cortar a string no primeiro asterisco encontrado
var resultado = nome.split("*", 1);

document.getElementById("resultado").value = resultado;



}</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Com `.substr()` e `indexOf()` você consegue pegar a substring do início (índice `0`) até a primeira ocorrência do asterisco (o `indexOf()` vai até o caractere anterior ao da ocorrência):

```
var resultado = nome.substr(0, nome.indexOf("*"));
```

Exemplo:

```js
function apagar(){
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;

   // Exemplo retornando só o modelo
   var resultado = nome.substr(0, nome.indexOf("*"));

   document.getElementById("resultado").value = resultado;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control" value="palio*Azul">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
  <label>Resultado</label>
      <input type="text" id="resultado" class="form-control" >
    </div>
  </div>
 <input type="button" id="botaoapagar" onclick="apagar();" value="Apagar">
```